# JavaScript not working after GitHub deployment

Tags: javascript, html, git, github

I am trying to host my developer profile on GitHub. I have a small javascript typing project I am working on that gets a quote from an API and lets you type the results showing your errors and WPM. It is a little rough right now and certainly needs work but it functions perfectly as is on my local machine. When I uploaded to gitHub though the css and html seemed to have worked fine but the quote and all the javascript functions that load when a new quote is loaded dont seem to work at all.

I am getting the following console error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at script.js:16"

I thought the GitHub may be useful aslo https://github.com/nicklandreth73/Nick-Landreth

```js
const randomQuoteApiUrl = 'https://api.quotable.io/random'
const quoteDisplayElement = document.getElementById('quoteDisplay')
const quoteInputElement = document.getElementById('quoteInput')
const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer')
const wpmElement = document.getElementById('wpm')
const errorsElement = document.getElementById('errors')


let errors
let minutes
let words
let wpm
let startTime

// checks at each input and performs neccesary operation
quoteInputElement.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const arrayQuote = quoteDisplayElement.querySelectorAll('span')
    const arrayValue = quoteInputElement.value.split('')

    let correct = true
    arrayQuote.forEach((characterSpan, index) => {
        const character = arrayValue[index]
        if (character == null) {
            characterSpan.classList.remove('correct')
            characterSpan.classList.remove('incorrect')
            correct = false
        }
        else if (character === characterSpan.innerText) {
            characterSpan.classList.add('correct')
            characterSpan.classList.remove('incorrect')
            addLength()
        } else {
            characterSpan.classList.add('incorrect')
            characterSpan.classList.remove('correct')
            correct = false
            removeLength()
        }
    })
    if (correct) renderNewQuote()

})
// gets a new quote from randomQuoteApi
function getRandomQuote() {
    return fetch(randomQuoteApiUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.content)
}
// resets all elements and gets a new quote
async function renderNewQuote() {
    const quote = await getRandomQuote()
    quoteInputElement.maxLength = '1'
    errors = 0
    quoteDisplayElement.innerHTML = ''
    quoteInputElement.value = null
    quote.split('').forEach(character => {
        const characterSpan = document.createElement('span')
        characterSpan.innerText = character
        quoteDisplayElement.appendChild(characterSpan)
    })
    startTimer()
    startTracking()
}
function addLength() {
    quoteInputElement.maxLength = (quoteInputElement.value.length + 1)
}
function removeLength() {
    if (quoteInputElement.maxLength >= 2) {
        quoteInputElement.maxLength = (quoteInputElement.value.length - 1)
    }
    errors++
}

// begins the timer
function startTimer() {
    timerElement.innerText = 0
    startTime = new Date()
    setInterval(() => {
        timerElement.innerText = "Time in seconds: " + parseInt(getTimerTime())
    }, 1000)

}
//gets the timer 
function getTimerTime() {
    return ((new Date() - startTime) / 1000)
}
//begins the tracking of words per minute and errors
function startTracking() {
    wpm = 0
    minutes = (getTimerTime() / 60)
    setInterval(() => {
        words = (quoteInputElement.value.length / 5)
        minutes = (getTimerTime() / 60)
        wpm = (words / minutes)
        wpmElement.innerText = "WPM:" + parseInt(wpm)
        errorsElement.innerText = errors
    }, 100)
}

renderNewQuote()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Speed Typing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="timer" id="timer"></div>
    <div class="wpm" id="wpm"></div>
    <div class="errors" id="errors"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="quote-display" id="quoteDisplay"></div>
        <textarea id="quoteInput" class="quote-input" maxlength="1" autofocus></textarea>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you got any errors in the browser console? Like a CORS error?

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of that. Looks like I did    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at script.js:16"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you script tag at the bottom of the `html` page before `body` tag,
or add `defer' in the script tag

The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.
When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/JavaScript" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It immediately worked with that and considering the error it makes perfect sense to me. I appreciate your time!